# Unable to change Spinnaker Time zone using configue file

Tags: spinnaker

I am trying to change spinnaker timezone that is hosted on my Aws Ec2 instance . I changed the value in spinnaker-local.yml and restart spinnaker service .
but its not showing the impact on my spinnaker management ui timezone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to change the timezone in the UI's `settings.js` file.

[This](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/blob/master/config/settings.js#L52) is the field that controls the timezone in the UI. Changing it really depends on how you manage Spinnaker's configuration, but that's what you'll want to change.

Comment: The link "This" is broken

Comment: Probably it's this link: https://github.com/spinnaker/deck/blob/master/halconfig/settings.js